# Fetching data from mongo using key in server js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am accepting username and phone from the front end and now i need to send phone to mongodb and based on that phone i need to get the details of a matching student's detail.Please help me to achieve this.

this is my server code:

```
server.post('/phone',urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
var resp={
  Username : req.body.username,
  phn:req.body.password
}
databaseInterface.studentDetail(resp.phn);
    res.json(resp.phn);

console.log(resp);
 res.send('username :' + req.body.username + 'passwrd:' + req.body.password);
})
```

this is my mongoDB code:

```
 function studentDetail(phn){
  User.findOne({'Father.PhoneNo':phn},function(err,studentcollection2){
    if (err) return phn(err);
    return phn(null, studentcollection2);
     }).select('-__v');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback that you are using has some problem.

```
function studentDetail(phn,callback){
  User.findOne({'Father.PhoneNo':phn},function(err,studentcollection2){
    if (err) return callback(err);
    return callback(null, studentcollection2);
     }).select('-__v');

}
```

for ur response,

```
databaseInterface.studentDetail(resp.phn,  function(err, val){
    if(err) res.send('ERROR!');
    else res.send('Response');
});
```

Not Tested!

Comment: but if i enter wrong phone it should give me error right??

Comment: Ho sorry that will return error if there is a problem with the database. Any ways thank you.

Answer (score 0):

FindOne will return a promise. You need to wait for it to be fulfilled before returning your json.

To achieve that, you need to do the following:

```
databaseInterface.studentDetail(resp.phn).then((data,error) => {
  res.json({response:data});
});
```

Your query seems wrong too.

```
function studentDetail(phone) {
  return [yourQuery].exec()
}
```

I believe that's it

Comment: Thanks but i am using mongoose for connection.But if i try the above query its giving me error like [User.find(...)].exec is not a function

Comment: Try to put the function inside the exec code and remove the .select part just for a test. Like find().exec(function);

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please refer mongoose documents it's quite different from mongoDB queries.